# Is it possible to pass an array in a form as a hidden field?

Tags: php

I have a form that submits various fields to create a new child job to the parent, but certain information from the parent job needs to be passed to the new job. There are a lot of fields that need to be passed to the new job, so I am wondering if it's possible to pass an array as a hidden field to a form.

I have searched online and found different options, such as passing the array as a concatenation, but I have too many fields to pass over. $job is the array I want to pass.

```
<form method="post" action="##">
    <input type="hidden" name="job" value="<?php echo $job; ?>">
</form>
```

The error I got with the code above is "array to string conversion", which makes sense, but how do I get around it?  There are many fields (probably close to 60) which need to be passed, so doing them one by one is not practical.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a loop or even serialize the value. Or you can use sessions and don't need to pass them around the client side.

Comment: or a JSON string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id of the parent job in the `hidden field`, on form submit action you can get the parent id and retrieve the information of that job.

```
<input type="hidden" name="parent_job_id" value="<?php echo $jobId; ?>">
```

Make sure which `index` holding the id of the parent job.

It seems `$job` is an `array`, you can not `echo` it, you can `echo` its index.